# Can Xtext replace flex and Yacc in an academic setting?

Tags: xtext

In my Programming Languages class the instructor has recommended that we download and play around with Flex and Yacc/Bison to prepare for future assignments. For various reasons, I would prefer to use an Eclipse plug-in, rather than install programs on my computer.

I found Xtext, which seems to encapsulate all the functionality necessary (and more), but my question is: Will Xtext be able to replace while still being able to do homework, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this question would be better answered by your instructor. They might have some assignments designed for Flex, Yacc and Bison, that wouldn't apply to Xtext; for example if they use some kind of automatic marking script.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I haven't asked the prof, but I feel his answer would be something like "what is xtext??". I think you are right that the assignments are designed for Flex/Bison.